# Llamar un método desde un adapter

Tags: java, android

Tengo un adapter que me carga los ítems de un list view y tengo un fragment que los toma.

**Adapter:**

```
package com.dmbteam.hotelapp.adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.ApplicationContext;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.MainActivity;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.R;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.fragments.NavigationBarFragment;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.fragments.RatesFragment;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.fragments.ReservationFragment;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.models.HotelReservationContactItem;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.models.RatesPageSettings;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.models.RoomRatesItem;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;

import static android.R.attr.fragment;
import static android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivity;

/**
 * The adapter used for the Rates Fragment
 *
 */
public class RatesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RoomRatesItem> {

    private ApplicationContext mContext;

    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private DisplayImageOptions mImageOptions;

    /**
     *
     * @param context
     *            the application context
     * @param items
     *            the RoomRates items to show
     */
    public RatesListAdapter(ApplicationContext context,
                            ArrayList<RoomRatesItem> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        mContext = context;

        mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        mImageOptions = com.dmbteam.hotelapp.MainActivity.buildImageOptions(
                ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT, true, true,
                MainActivity.dipsToPixels(mContext, 5), 0,
                R.drawable.action_bar_hotel_logo);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.rates_list_item, null);


        if (position % 2 > 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.drawer_grey_light));
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.drawer_grey));
        }

        RoomRatesItem item = getItem(position);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ratesListTitleTextView);
        title.setText(item.getRoomTitle());

        TextView description = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ratesListDescriptionTextView);
        description.setText(item.getRoomDescription());


        TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratesListRatesTextView);
        price.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        });

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ratesListItemImageView);
        mImageLoader.displayImage(item.getRoomPicture(mContext), image,
                mImageOptions);



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Frament:**

```
package com.dmbteam.hotelapp.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.ApplicationContext;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.R;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.adapters.RatesListAdapter;
import com.dmbteam.hotelapp.models.RatesPageSettings;

public class RatesFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = RatesFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private ListView mRatesList;

    private ApplicationContext mAppContext;

    public static RatesFragment newInstance(ApplicationContext appContext) {

        RatesFragment fragment = new RatesFragment();
        fragment.mAppContext = appContext;

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rates, container, false);

        RatesPageSettings ratesPageSettings = mAppContext
                .getParsedApplicationSettings().getRatesPageSettings();

        mRatesList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratesFragmentListView);

        mRatesList.setAdapter(new RatesListAdapter(mAppContext,
                ratesPageSettings.getRoomRatesList()));

        return view;
    }

    Public void llamado(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    mContext.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Entonces como el método start activity no existe en los adapter, pensé en ves del poner el staractivity poner un código que me llame el método "llamado" que esta en mi Frament desde mi adapter

Es posible? como?

Answer (score 1):

Para llamar el método `startActivity()` es necesario el `Context`. En tu `adapter` estas recibiendo el `Contexto` el cual es necesario para realizar el `Intent`, te sugiero usar `Context` en lugar de `ApplicationContext`  :

```
 public RatesListAdapter(Context  context,
                            ArrayList<RoomRatesItem> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        mContext = context;
        ...
        ...
    }
```

por lo tanto este context lo puedes usar para realizar el `Intent` y abrir otra Activity:

```
TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratesListRatesTextView);
    price.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext .startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

---

*Recuerda que las `Activity` que sean usadas en la aplicación deben estar registradas en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Ésta es la forma correcta de hacerlo. PD: [Dile NO a la notación hungara](http://jakewharton.com/just-say-no-to-hungarian-notation/)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes utilizar una interface

1) Creas la interface de la misma manera que creas una clase pero al seleccionar el tipo colocas "interface"

```
public interface miInterface{
    void mtdResultado(String resultado);

}
```

2) Dentro del adaptador instancias la interface y la colocas como parámetro de entrada en el constructor de la clase adaptador

```
miInterface listener;
public tuAdapatador(miInterface listener)
{
this.listener = listener;
}
```

3) Desde la clase donde instancias el adaptador creas una instancia de la interface, te va a quedar algo así:

```
   miInterface listenerLectura = new miInterface() {
       @Override
       public void mtdResultado(String resultado) {
          //Aqui pones el metodo que quieres llamar tiene que estar en esta clase
       }
   };
```

4) En alguna parte de tu adaptador es donde quieres llamar el método, hay colocas lo siguiente:

```
listener.mtdResultado("ProcesoRealizado");
```

Cuando hagas esto el mensaje ("ProcesoRealizado") va a llegar a el lugar de la clase principal donde instanciaste la interface y hay puedes colocar el metodo que quieres llamar, espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos